# Can I define environment variables for a compound command only once?

Tags: bash, sh

Is there a way to define environment variables for each command in a compound command without repeating the definitions? For example, can this be shortened without exporting X1, X2 and X3:

```
X1=foo X2=bar X3=baz command1 && X1=foo X2=bar X3=baz command2
```

Comment: Only if you run them in a subshell, which is clumsy: `A=A B=b C=abc bash -c 'echo $A; echo $B; echo $C'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the environment variables too survive the command, one approach is to put the whole command in a subshell:

```
( X1=foo; X2=bar; X3=baz; command1 && command2 ; )
```

If `command1` or `command2` run in separate processes, you may need to export the variables so that those commands see them:

```
( X1=foo; X2=bar; X3=baz; export X1 X2 X3 ; command1 && command2 ; )
```

Comment: The issue isn't whether `command1` and `command2` are in subshells, but if they run in separate *processes*. If `tmp.bash` contains the single command `echo $FOO`, `( FOO=3; ( . ./tmp.bash ) )` still produces output; `(FOO=3; ( bash ./tmp.bash ) )` does not; but `(export FOO=3; ( bash ./tmp.bash ) )` does.